# How to analyse the first line of a txt file in bash

Tags: bash

I need to check with my Bash script, if there is a Shebang in the frist line of a .txt file.
This is my code so far:

```
#Lists all valid parameters#

listParameter(){

    echo "Invalid parameter. Please use one of the following keywords:"
    echo -e "(txxxxx | stat | all | plag)\n"
}
 

if [ -z $1 ]
then
    listParameter
    exit 1

else
    if [ ${1:0:1} == "t" ]
    then
        if [ ! -f "$1" ]
        then 
            echo -e "File missing. Please import $1 to this path.\n"
            exit 1
        else 
            FILE = $1
            FIRSTLINE="head -n 1 $FILE"
            if [FIRSTLINE == "#!"]
            then
                echo "Lorem Ipsum"
            else
                echo "Lorem Ipsum"
            fi
        fi
```

I need to make different "tests" by different command line parameters.
So first of all I checked if §1 is starting with a t. Than I know its txxxxx parameter.
txxxxx is the name of a txt file.
Than I check if this file exist. If yes I want to check, if the first row of the file starts with a "#!". But this is not working and i dont know why.
The txxxxx file and the bash script are in the same folder.
So all in all, I just dont know how I can open and analyse a certain .txt file... :/

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Run your script through [Shell Check](https://shellcheck.net) to catch some syntax errors.

Comment: You have the right idea with `FIRSTLINE="head -n 1 $FILE"`, except you're just storing that command as a string in the variable.

Comment: so that should be `FIRSTLINE="$( head -n 1 "${FILE}" )";`. After that, the conditional you're using wont work, but you did the same thing correctly earlier on; you want to check the first 2 characters of the string only

Comment: I got it guys, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Worth the upvote for your effort in including your attempt in your question and for your good explanation of exactly what problem you were having (both have been elusive lately....)

Comment: `if [ -z $1 ]` is not what you want.  If no first parameter is passed, this will do what you expect, but not for the reason you expect.  `[ -z $1 ]` does not evaluate true because `$1` is the empty string, but because `-z` is not the empty string.  But you will get very unexpected behavior if the first parameter contains whitespace.   You ought to use quotes: `[ -z "$1" ]`

Comment: `[FIRSTLINE == "#!"]` will give you an error message (_[FIRSTLINE : Command ont found_). You could do a `[[  ${FIRSTLINE:0:2} == '#!'  ]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not executing the "head -n 1..." command, but treating it as a string. To run it use:

```
FIRSTLINE=$(head -n 1 "$FILE")
```

Then you probably want to check if first line starts with shebang, not necessarily is shebang.

Comment: `FILE=$1`
   `FIRSTLINE=$(head -n 1 "$FILE")`
   `if [ ${FIRSTLINE:0:2} == "#!" ]`

It worked thanks :D
Yeah, i just picked the first 2 letters from FIRSTLINE like I did it above and it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the builtin `read`. You don't need to call an external command like `head` and invoke a subshell.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
if IFS= read -r firstline < "$file" && [[ $firstline = '#!'* ]]
then
    printf 'The file %s contains shebang\n' "$file"
fi
```

As an aside, you shouldn't use capitalized variable names for your own variables in shell programming, by convention. Environment variables and internal shell variables are capitalized. All other variable names should be lower case. This convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace matters.  The line `if [FIRSTLINE == "#!"]` is incorrect, as it attempts to executes a command named `[FIRSTLINE`, which probably does not exist.  You want:

```
 if [ "$FIRSTLINE" = "#!" ]
```

Also, instead of `if [ -z $1 ]`, you ought to use `if [ -z "$1" ]`